# How to verify a value from a Search list using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have to verify a record from the search list. How can I do it effectively and in a reusable way? I search a keyword that returns 100s of records and then verify my expected search keyword is displayed in the search list.

Here is my code

```
void searchlist()
{       
    String expectedresult = "Abragar, Avarii";
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("nav-user-search")));
    WebElement searchlist =  driver.findElement(By.id("nav-user-search"));
    searchlist.sendKeys("abra");
    searchlist.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);   
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Abragar, Avarii")));
    WebElement element =  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Abragar, Avarii"));
    System.out.println("search result is " + element);
    //WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(linkText)))
    //System.out.println(element.getText());

    if(element.equals(expectedresult)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Search is passed");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Search is failed");
    }       
}
```

HTML is below

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td><a href="/Admins/Configuration/Users/DisplayUser.aspx?UserId=2327761">Abragar, Milai</a></td>
    <td><a href="/Admins/Configuration/Users/ImpersonateUser.aspx?UserId=2327761">Impersonate</a></td>
    <td>2302319@aol.com</td>
    <td>228-454-3223</td>
    <td>Conventional User</td>
    <td>07/19/2017</td>
    <td>Active</td>
</tr>
```

i need to verify "Abragar, Milai" is displayed in the search list

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take another approach, using the xpath.

```
void searchlist(String searchKey, String expectedresult, WebDriver driver)
    {
        // Webdriver wait
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        // wait until the search box is displayed
        WebElement searchlist  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("nav-user-search")));
        // enter the search word
        searchlist.sendKeys(searchKey);
        // hit enter
        searchlist.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        // wait until the search results is displayed with the expected result
        List<WebElement> elements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//table[@id='userTable']//tr[td/a[contains(.,'" + expectedresult + "')]]")));
        // check if there is any matching elements
        if(elements.size()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Search is passed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Search is failed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please tell:-
now how do you print the element that's been retrieved for matching the "expected result".

Comment: `WebElement exceptedElement = elements.get(0)` and then use the `exceptedElement` as if you got the element using findElement.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a reusable way, you want to make the `searchList()` method reusable by adding the `keyword` parameter and passing in the search keyword and then have it do the searching and validation.

Some notes:

1. Many times `wait.until()` returns the thing waited for, e.g. a `WebElement`. Using this, you can do things like the below and then use `e` for later steps.

   ```
   WebElement e = wait.until(...);
   e.sendKeys("some text");
   ```
2. You had a `WebDriverWait` declared in the middle of the method. I'm not sure if that was intentional? You use `wait` on the second line so you must have more than one defined on the page? I moved the declaration to the top and reused it throughout the method.
3. On the first line, you declared the `expectedResult` but then never used it. I removed all instances of "Abragar, Avarii" and replaced them with the `keyword` parameter.
4. Instead of writing your own comparisons for validation, use a library like JUnit or TestNG. They make validations a LOT easier plus they handle all kinds of other things like tagging scripts with labels and being able to kick off runs using those labels, e.g. Smoke, FullRegression, Pri1s, etc.
5. To do the validation, I've added an XPath that searches for the line that contains the keyword in the proper place. By using `.findElements()` (plural), it returns a list and we can check the count of elements in that list to ensure that it's 1. NOTE: if you use `.findElement()` (singular) here, it will throw if the element is not found. We don't want the code to throw, we'd rather have the Assert fail because the count was 0 instead of 1. It makes debugging easier.

   ```
   //tr[@role='row']/td/a[contains(@href, 'DisplayUser.aspx')][.='" + keyword + "']]
   ^ search for a TR that contains role='row'
                    ^ that has a TD child
                       ^ that has an A child
                         ^ which contains 'DisplayUser.aspx' in the href
                                                              ^ and also contains the keyword in the contained text (of the A)
   ```

The updated and now reusable method

```
void searchlist(String keyword)
{       
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement searchlist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("nav-user-search")));
    searchlist.sendKeys("abra");
    searchlist.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);   
    Assert.assertEquals(1, driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']/td/a[contains(@href, 'DisplayUser.aspx')][.='" + keyword + "']]")).Count, "Verify keyword was found in the search results");
}
```

Call the method like

```
searchList("Abragar, Avarii");
```